# AddThis button will not work inside AJAX, but will work normally

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, addthis

Basically, this is what I'm doing.
User visits site, loads "index.html"
Within index.html, it automatically loads, through AJAX, "details.html" into a DIV.
I put an ADDTHIS button on "details.html".  However, for some reason , the roll-over doesn't work.

When I visit details.html in the browser, the roll-over works. I'm guessing it's because of the AJAX?

```
<a class="addthis_button"  href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=250&amp;pub=xa-4adf7e45288f5b21">
<img src="http://s7.addthis.com/static/btn/sm-share-en.gif" width="83" height="16" alt="Bookmark and Share" style="border:0;margin-top:16px;"/></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pub=xa-4adf7e45288f5b21"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly, in the callback of the ajax function, bind the roll-over to the add-this button.

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(){
     $('.addthis_button').hover(
       function(){
         //do mouse over
       },function(){
         //do mouse out
     });
   }
 });
```

you can also try

```
$('.addthis_button').live('mouseover',function(){//do mouseover});
$('.addthis_button').live('mouseout',function(){//do mouseout});
```

i've never used live, but it seems like it would work for you since your add_this button's get created after the $(document).ready()

Answer (score 14):

I recently ran in to issues with using AddThis on an all AJAX site and was able to come up with a couple of solutions for this issue.

It turns out there is a variable that you can pass when loading the AJAX script as well as a way to re-initialize the script if the DOM is reloaded via AJAX.
I have posted the full solution in detail on my blog here:

http://joecurlee.com/2010/01/21/how-to-use-addthis-with-ajax-and-overflowauto/

To briefly summarize, the solution is loading AddThis with the variable domready=1 appended, and re-initializing the script by deleting the initial load and then reloading the script dynamically:

```
var script = 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#domready=1';
if (window.addthis){
    window.addthis = null;
}
$.getScript( script );
```

Comment: Just chiming in that for me this solution did not work. I had to do a callback in the `.getScript()` which ran `addthis.init()` for the button to show up.

Comment: This was basically it for me. However, the clearing of some additional variables was necessary, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650226/addthis-not-working-with-ajax?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

addthis.toolbox(".addthis_toolbox");

Answer (score 2):

Ran in the same problem and this solved it for me in all major browsers (IE6+, FF, Safari in MAC/XP):

http://joecurlee.com/2010/01/21/how-to-use-addthis-with-ajax-and-overflowauto/comment-page-1/#comment-24

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Fixed it with the following code. I hope that fixes it for you too.

**Original Method:**

```
    var script = 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js?domready=1';
    if (window.addthis){
        window.addthis = null;
    }
    $.getScript( script );
```

**New Method:**

```
<script>
var script = 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#domready=1';
if (window.addthis) {
    window.addthis = null;
    window._adr = null;
    window._atc = null;
    window._atd = null;
    window._ate = null;
    window._atr = null;
    window._atw = null;
}
$.getScript(script);
</script>
```

**In AJAX REQUEST you can use like this:-**

```
$.ajax({
    url:Url,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    success: function(res){
        var script = 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#domready=1';
        if (window.addthis) {
            window.addthis = null;
            window._adr = null;
            window._atc = null;
            window._atd = null;
            window._ate = null;
            window._atr = null;
            window._atw = null;
        }
        $.getScript(script);
        // your custom code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the script is calling the onLoad event of javascript and using this ajax call won't actually trigger that event. You could try other "share this" widget?

Like http://sharethis.com/#STS=g12m3ugh.21zb
or pre-load that button?

Can you post a little bit more of the story on what are you doing?

Answer (score 0):

Is details.html a fully compliant page on it's own? HTML, BODY, HEAD tags, etc?

If so, I think things can get kind screwy when you try to load it into another page. I would either change details.html to just include the barebones markup that you need - or - if you need it to still be individually accessible - you could use jQuery to strip out the needed bits after the ajax call and only inject that portion.

Details.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="details">
    The needy bits.......
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.html

```
$("#targetDivID").load("detail.html #details");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this snippet of .js to the .html you are loading. Replace "#atbutton" with your button's selector.

addthis.button("#atbutton");